# HQL query with 2 column Sub Join

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa, hql

I have a table `price`:

```
| id | price | product_id | date | other_columns... |
```

I have the following query to return the latest `price` row for each `product_id`:

```
select p1.*
from price p1
  right join (
               select
                 p2.product_id,
                 p2.id,
                 max(p2.date)
               from price p2
               GROUP BY p2.product_id
             ) p2 ON p2.id = p1.id;
```

When I run `Explain` plan, and from running against a large table this seems to be the most efficient way of achieving this (correct me if I'm wrong!).

I need to convert this to `HQL` to use with `Spring Data JPA`. So far I have the sub query:

```
(SELECT p2.id, MAX(p2.date) FROM Price p2 GROUP BY p2.product)
```

That seems to be the easy part. How do I now join this so I can get the full latest `Price` for each product?

---

I have tried other queries e.g.

```
select
  p1.*
from price p1
where p1.date = (
  select max(p2.date)
  from price p2
  where p1.product_id = p2.product_id
)
```

Which is much easier to convert to `HQL` but seems to be worse performance-wise.

Comment: As far as i know Hibernate does not allow subqueries to join with:"Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses":  [JBoss Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries)

Comment: @CannedMoose I thought that might be the case :( Is there any other way I could achieve this?

Comment: I have not tried it but saw an article that describes creating a view to achieve it here : [How to perform SQL JOINs on a sub-query in Hibernate](https://bit-insomnia.de/en/2015/08/15/how-to-perform-sql-joins-on-a-sub-query-in-hibernate/). But maybe you prefer to go with your subquery.